# Grabbing Nx root package version into workspace package.json

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

Besides hardcoding, is there a way/shortcut to programmatically get a matching package & version from the root level `package.json`? I’m creating a generator that generates a react app and I want the package within this generated react app to match the one in the root level `package.json`.

Besides hardcoding the version

```
/proj
  /apps
    /test-app
      package.json    // <--- "antd": "^4.20.3"
  package.json        // <--- "antd": "^4.20.3"
```

Comment: Inside the `apps/` there is no `package.json`,
If you are using `NX Workspace` the package.json is found on the main root and every project inside the `app/` folder has a `project.json` that is connected directly to `package.json`

Comment: @liondancer did you find out how to do this without hardcoding the version? I tried `*` wildcard for `react-native` however I end up with a different react-native version for the root package.json and the app package.json